# "If" function not working properly Python 3.6"

Tags: python-3.x

I just started learning how to code yesterday and I can't figure out what could be wrong with this:

```
print("Enter yout age: ")

    age = input()

    if age == 0:
        print("So you don't exist?")
    else:
        print("So you do exist!")
```

When I run that even if I input "0" it ignores the if line and I get "So you do exist!" every time.

Comment: what is the type of the `age` variable?

Comment: Try to cast your value to int maybe ? `int(age)`

Comment: please format your code with tab.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the input to `int`. Use proper indentation.

```
print("Enter your age: ")
age = int(input())
if age == 0:
    print("So you don't exist?")
else:
    print("So you do exist!")
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah because `input()` return type is `str`;
use `age = int(input())`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a `string` to a `number`, so it's wrong. If you parse it, you will be able to compare :)

Try this:

```
print("Enter yout age: ")
age = int(input())
if age == 0:
    print("So you don't exist?")
else:
    print("So you do exist!")
```